# Drawing a vertical line in a gridview cell

Tags: c#, gridview

I want to demarcate the values of a given cell in a gridview into three without using "|" but a vertical line the length of the column in the gridview.

```
for (int i = 0; i < subjectCount; i++)
{
    TableCell totals = new TableHeaderCell();
    totals.ColumnSpan = grid.Columns.Count - 1;
    totals.BackColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.ControlDark;// System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(#c0c0c0);
    totals.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
    totals.Font.Size = FontUnit.Medium;
    totals.Font.Bold = true;

    //totals.Text = "40|60%|100%"; would love to display and image in between them like 40-vertical image-60-vertical image-100

    totals.Text = "40 | 60 | 100";

    row.Cells.Add(totals);

    t.Rows.AddAt(1, row);
}
```

Comment: You didn't mention whether you are using WPF or Winforms?

Comment: Unfortunately `DataGridView` doesn't support [merged cells](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/winformsdatacontrols/thread/fea3dcff-5447-450a-8f7c-bb1c4f63371d/). But, you may implement them [yourself](http://forums.codeguru.com/showthread.php?415930-DataGridView-Merging-Cells). Also, you may consider switching to WPF, as this environment provides easier ways to customize controls.

Comment: Dzienny, I kinda mixed up my comment, am using webforms not winforms. so any help?

Comment: I see. It explains `GridView`. Anyway, sorry, I haven't programmed for asp.net. I did check the problem though. [This](http://forums.asp.net/t/1757382.aspx/1) code seems relevant. You probably want to have 3 columns and then just merge the header that is over them.